# How to get rowid on click of a group column?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with group columns like

```
+[col A]
|
---+[Col B]
   |
   ---+[Col C]  
       - Row 1
       - Row 2
       - Row n
```

Grid code

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid({
datastr: data,
datatype: "jsonstring",
colModel: [
    { name: 'Col A',          key:true, width: 75 },
    { name: 'someId',     key:true, width: 75, hidden: true },
    { name: 'Col B',      key:true, width: 0 },
    { name: 'Col C',      key:true, width: 75},
], 
sortname: 'Col A',
grouping: true,
gridview:true,
onSelectRow: function(rowid) {
    //do stuff here

},
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["Col A", "Col B","Col C"],
    groupColumnShow: [false, false,false],
    groupText: ["<b>{0}</b>"," <b>{0}</b>","<b>{0}</b>"],                    
    groupSummary: [false, false],
    groupCollapse: false,
    ExpandColClick: false,
    subGrid: false,
    ExpandColumn: true                       
}
```

My onSelectRow get executed when I click on any of the 'Row x' but I want to get rowid on click of [Col C].

I didn't find any straight forward way to get it. Please suggest how could it be possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Need to show what code you are currently using

Comment: added grid creation code snippet.

Comment: It's wrong to use `key:true` in more as one column. About your main question: the group header (`+[Col C]` for example) is **the header** over some rows of data. It has no rowid.

Comment: One more remark: you should never use `name` in `colModel` which contains spaces. `name` will be used to construct `id` values of some internal elements of grid. HTML5 not allows to use spaces in id. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): "The value must not contain any space characters." On the other side you can use `label` property which can contains spaces and can be any HTML fragment. Alternatively (instead of `label` property) you can use `colNames`.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for suggestions. I wanted to get the hidden cell ('someid') value on click of 'Col C'. I had to take long route now to do the same i.e. to iterate through all rows and comparing few params.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really difficult to follow you. What you mean under "click of 'Col C'"? The grouped grid contains rows with grouping header with **content** of `'Col C'`. If you have for example 5 rows with the same value abc in `'Col C'` then you will have -abc in the grouping header. The user can click on "-" before "abc" to collapse the 5 rows. The header will be displayed as +abc. The click on "+" before abc will display the next 5 rows back. So there are no 'Col C' and no `someId`. There are 5 rows with different `someId` values. All the rows have the same "abc" value in `'Col C'`.

Comment: The user can click on "+" before some group. So one can't speak about some rowid or some value from the hidden cell ('someid'). I have really no idea what you want to implement. Probably it's better if you post some demo and explain on the example what you want?